# Failed to Parse error : Unexpected token on "import" with Istanbul

Tags: import, protractor, instrumentation, istanbul, esprima

I am using Istanbul for code coverage of Protractor Tests.

In the process of Instrumenting the source Code I am getting a "Failed to parse, Unexpected Token" error, and after going through the error it is found that the "import" token is creating the issue.

Been working on Angular2 and Typescript.

I am using command : istanbul instrument ./dir/to/instrument/ -o ./out/dir/

Istanbul by default uses esprima parser to parse the code before instrumenting.
This is a parsing error, but I am unable to find any solution to resolve it.

Istanbul:v0.4.5

Esprima parser:v3.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
npx nyc instrument [input-file] [output-file]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).